# How to get value radio on table using click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get value of radio in table using click event.Note , get value of radio in column

```html
<table id="div_table" width="500px" border="2px" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" >
<tr>
<td >Column Name1</td>
<td>Column Name2</td>
<td >Column Name3</td>
</tr>

<tr >
<td >PN1</td>
<td ><input type="radio" name="RD_CHECK" value="ABC">ABC</td>
<td ></td>
</tr>

<tr >
<td >PX2</td>
<td ><input type="radio" name="RD_CHECK" value="XYZ">XYZ <input type="radio" name="RD_CHECK" value="CBA">CBA</td>
<td ><input type="radio" name="RD_CHECK" value="123">123 <input type="radio" name="RD_CHECK" value="456">456</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Ok , Example: I check radio of column2 but it not work.

```js
 $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $('body').on('click','#div_table tbody tr', function ()
            {
                if ($("input[type='radio']").is(':checked') == true && $(this).find('td:eq')==1)
                {
                    //value of radio in Column2
                    alert('This is Column 2 and value = '+$("input:checked").val());
                }
                else
                {
                  // value of radio in Column3
                    alert('This is Column 3 and value = '+$("input:checked").val());
                }
            });
   });
```

Give me advised.Thank guys.

Comment: Working fine here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wq6buraz/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$("input[type='radio']").is(':checked') == true` Will get the `checked` property of only the first matching `<input>`. If your first radio isn't checked, this fails.
- `$(this).find('td:eq') == 1` Will always be true since even a jQuery constructor with no matches returns an object (truthy value).

Instead, attach the event to the radio buttons themselves. You can get the column by finding the [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) of the [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) `<td>`. To get the value simply use the context of your event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '#div_table  tr :radio', function () {
        var col = $(this).closest('td').index();
        alert('This is Column ' + col + ' and value = ' + this.value);
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/c4h38v41/)